# What pattern helps to compose nested views at runtime?

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

Are there any design patterns to compose views within a parent view during runtime? Say we are composing the views in a workflow tab and views in the tabcontrol depend on the country, store type and/or other conditions.

This is a MVP, WPF, PRISM application.

Comment: Hmm, why not use DataTemplateSelectors which select the DataTemplates based on the locale or other criteria?

Comment: Sounds like [functional composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29) to me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest design pattern I can think of is [decorator pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Decorator_pattern). That said, are you nesting views, or enabling/disabling/auto-populating fields based on other selections in the UI, in which case you may want to use the [strategy pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Strategy_pattern)?

Answer (score 1):

Would a some form of Factory suffice?

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
    var dynamicView = ViewFactory.CreateView(countryCode, storeType, otherConditions);
    Render(dynamicView);
```

or

```
    var countryView = CountryViewFactory.Create(countryCode);
    var storeTypeView = StoreTypeViewFactory.Create(storeType);
    var otherView = OtherViewFactory.Create(otherConditions);
    RenderPartial("CountrySection", countryView);
    RenderPartial("StoreTypeSection", storeTypeView);
    RenderPartial("OtherSection", otherView);
```

Comment: Chris, we are using Unity for DI else factory would be one my choices too. but i was actually wondering whats the best design pattern that can be followed for this scenario!

Comment: The only other thing I can think off is the Composite pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) but they may not be appropriate depending on the structure of the views you have.